# Output only the sad students from a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following declaration:

```
calculate_sad_moods([]):-!.
calculate_sad_moods([X2|Rest2]) :- 
    (sad(X2),write(`One of our sad students is: `),write(X2),nl);
calculate_sad_moods(Rest2).
```

When I call it like this:

```
?- calculate_sad_moods([
    ivan, dragan, petkan, borislav, damyan, ani, petyr, ivo
]).
```

I end up with a very long list like this (It's ok, but it has dublicate records):

```
One of our sad students is: ivan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: dragan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: dragan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: petkan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: petkan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: borislav
Yes.
One of our sad students is: borislav
Yes.
One of our sad students is: damyan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: damyan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: damyan
Yes.
One of our sad students is: ani
Yes.
One of our sad students is: ani
Yes.
One of our sad students is: ani
Yes.
One of our sad students is: petyr
Yes.
One of our sad students is: petyr
```

When I change the declaration to:

```
calculate_sad_moods([]):-!.
calculate_sad_moods([X2|Rest2]) :- 
    write(`One of our sad students is: `),write(X2),nl,
calculate_sad_moods(Rest2).
```

I end up with this (It's not OK, because not everybody is sad, but it has no dublicate records):

```
One of our sad students is: ivan
One of our sad students is: dragan
One of our sad students is: petkan
One of our sad students is: borislav
One of our sad students is: damyan
One of our sad students is: ani
One of our sad students is: petyr
One of our sad students is: ivo
```

How can I output only the sad students and only once? I've tried adding brackets and several other tricks and still - Nothing.
I have no other ideas left where to look.

**P.S: Here's how the sad declaration looks like**

```
[...]
sad(damyan) :- 
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,chemistry)),hasExam(damyan,chemistry));
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,biology),hasExam(damyan,biology)));
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,math),hasExam(damyan,math))).
sad(ani) :- 
    (not(lovesExam(ani,chemistry)),hasExam(ani,chemistry));
    (not(lovesExam(ani,biology),hasExam(ani,biology)));
    (not(lovesExam(ani,math),hasExam(ani,math))).
[...]
```

It'is still very obscure, but I'm still learning the basics...

Comment: Since the only difference between the two programs is whether or not you call the `sad` function, it would probably be helpful to include it in your question.

Comment: It looks like it is asking you every time whether the student is sad, could you possibly include your decleration of sad as well so we can see the full code for this example?

Comment: @Tacroy this is prolog, he's not exactly 'calling a function' but evaluating a predicate which is probably simply defined as a clause for each sad student; e.g. `sad(ani).`

Comment: @l4mpi I know, but he used the verb "call" in his question so I figured he would be more likely to understand "call the function" over "evaluate the predicate", even if it's not strictly accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you placed the cut at useless place. Try instead of a cut to use if/then/else, it's far clearer.

```
calculate_sad_moods([]).
calculate_sad_moods([X2|Rest2]) :-
    (   sad(X2)
    ->  write('One of our sad students is: '),
        write(X2),
        nl
    ;   true),
    calculate_sad_moods(Rest2).
```

And you have some typo

```
...
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,chemistry)),hasExam(damyan,chemistry));
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,biology),hasExam(damyan,biology)));
...
```

note the seconde line should read

```
    (not(lovesExam(damyan,biology)),hasExam(damyan,biology));
```

You should use setof/3 if you want to *collect* sad students.

Comment: Good answer as always... the reason why this works without printing duplicates is because the if/else construct does a cut after evaluating the predicate and thus stops the `sad` clause from backtracking, right?

Comment: @l4mpi: yes. At first glance I wrote something similar to your code, but the cut seems such an intimidating concept for newcomers, I prefer avoid as much as possible

Comment: It would probably be more accurate to say the if/else construct does not create a choice point to be backtracked into in the first place. In the original this is split into two clauses and multiple clauses always create a choice points. This is partly why when you see a conditional in the first clause you usually see its negation in the second clause. ("Reverse correctness")

Comment: @DanielLyons: true. I have by myself an habit to read the cut procedurally, because I learned Prolog on my old interpreter that doesn't have ->/2.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve with your predicate - should it print one student at a time and abort if the user accepts, or should it simply print out all sad students in the list? These would be two slightly different predicates.

As to why you're getting duplicates, I guess something in your `sad` predicate leads to backtracking, meaning it can be evaluated multiple times - use the `trace` functionality of the prolog interpreter to find out where the backtracking happens. While the best thing to do would be fixing the `sad` predicate to not backtrack, a workaround would be using a cut after the `sad` which prevents the backtracking:

```
calculate_sad_moods([]):-!.
calculate_sad_moods([X2|Rest2]) :- 
    (sad(X2), !, write(`One of our sad students is: `),
     write(X2), nl, calculate_sad_moods(Rest2));
    calculate_sad_moods(Rest2).
```

The cut means that we need to recurse into `calculate_sad_moods` after writing the output as we can't reach the `or` part of the clause anymore (it's been cut away too).

If you require the behaviour that the predicate evaluates to true after the first sad student found you could achieve this by using another `;` before the backtracking in the sadness case:

```
calculate_sad_moods([X2|Rest2]) :- 
    (sad(X2), !, write(`One of our sad students is: `),
    write(X2), (nl; calculate_sad_moods(Rest2))); %only recurse if user says 'no'
    calculate_sad_moods(Rest2).
```

As a final note, the predicate name is very misleading as you don't actually calculate anything; maybe `print_sad_students` would be a more fitting name.